# Can I label a Manipulate panel?

Tags: manipulate, labeling

I wasn't able to find a way to label a `Manipulate` panel (not the sliders, etc.). Is it indeed not (directly) possible?

Comment: It might be useful if you added a bit more information to your question. You already got a nice answer, which would merit a touching up the question a bit.

Comment: @Yves Klett: Indeed, I've got a very good and detailed answer from Karsten 7. to my question (many thanks to Karsten for that). I wouldn't know though, what I should add or how I should have formulated my question?

Comment: Yeah, @Karsten7. interpreted you very compact question just right, but withouth his answer some mockup images or code to illustrate what you´d like to have would have been useful to eliminate any ambiguousness (e.g. the definition of "panel"). Glad you got a great answer in any case!

Comment: @YvesKlett: Oh, ok, now I see what you mean and you're right. I will consider this next time I'll ask a question.

Comment: I just see you have one closing vote (perhaps cast before or without seeing the answer). Just in case this should get closed, you can ask for re-opening, which I would support then.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Manipulate[u, {u, 0, 1}, FrameLabel -> "FrameLabel"]
```

> [image]

or

```
Manipulate[u, {u, 0, 1}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"FrameLabel 1", "FrameLabel 2"}, {"FrameLabel 3", "FrameLabel 4"}}]
```

> [image]

or

```
Labeled[Manipulate[u, {u, 0, 1}], "Label"]
```

> [image]

or

```
Manipulate[u, Style["Label", 12, Bold], {u, 0, 1}]
```

> [image]

or

```
Panel[Manipulate[
  Panel[u, "Label 1", FrameMargins -> Large], {u, 0, 1}, 
  Paneled -> False], "Label 2"]
```

> [image]